# input() on angular2 is not working Properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

first of all this is my GIT repository where you can see the code:

https://github.com/eshk12/myDogs

I try to practice some parts from the lesson so I have create ANG2 Project call "myDogs".

in the porject I have 3 components,root and DogList,dog.

i have an issue in "DogList" component when I try to send the value "currentDog" as "dogC" to the component "Dog", and error came up and said:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection:

Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dogC' since it isn't a known property of 'dog'. ("
  <div>
    <dog *ngFor="let currentDog of dogs"
            [ERROR ->][dogC]="currentDog"
    >
    </dog>
"): DogList@3:12

; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException { message="Template parse errors:\nC...</dog>\n"): DogList@3:12",  stack="BaseException@http://loc...js/dist/zone.js:426:22\n",  constructor=BaseException(),  more...}
zone.js (line 461)
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dogC' since it isn't a known property of 'dog'. ("
  <div>
    <dog *ngFor="let currentDog of dogs"
            [ERROR ->][dogC]="currentDog"
    >
    </dog>
"): DogList@3:12
throw new Error("Uncaught (in promise): " + value);
```

I tried to "ul li"ed it like that: *ngFor="let dogC of dogs" and its work,

but when I send it to the other component error come up.

The original GIT repository from my teacher that work: https://github.com/rotemx/Class4-MyMusic

Thanks in advance to those who will help me find the problem.

Comment: up, dont forget me -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dog component:

```
export class Dog {
  @Input() public DogC: DogModel;
}                 ^^^^
```

In your DogsList component template:

```
<dog *ngFor="let currentDog of dogs"
        [dogC]="currentDog"
>       ^^^^^^
</dog>
```

You defined the Input as `DogC` but you are trying to bind to `dogC`. Javascript/Typescript is case-sensitive. Change the Input `DogC` to `dogC`and it will work.

By the way, it is not recommended to keep the templates of components in separate folders from the components themselves. Check out [the official Angular 2 style guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html) for the recommended file structure and naming conventions.

Comment: OMG I can't Belive that was my error. Thank you very much friend :)